# How To change the order of input sockets of a node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to change the order/position of the input sockets of a Geometry-Node in order to avoid intersecting connections?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: **No, not possible** (at least not with the nodes integrated in Blender and not without modifying the source code). However, you could move the nodes to a group and do the wiring there, but that seems a bit impractical...

Comment: ah I see, you could make a "Wrapper" around an integrated node which serves as a customized fascade to the wrapped node. But this seems really impractically for the benefit of little improved style.